# Is there a better expression for "over there" than "tie"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I usually understand **tie** as **there**, that is, meaning a place that's being spoken about or otherwise implied. Does it also have the meaning of **over there**, in the sense when I want to refer to a place within the line of sight (which I would presumably be pointing to simultaneously)? (Not in the sense of *way over there in Africa*.) If not, how would I modify it to have such connotation in written text?

I was considering **ĉi tie** because I could, in a close analogy, accompany **ĉi tiel** or **ĉi tiu** by demonstration or pointing at someone, respectively, but to my best knowledge, **ĉi tie** is **here** which is very different. I'd like to explicitly refer to a place which is proximate but not coincident with me.

Examples:

> Ĉu ni bezonas iri al butiko? — Ne, mi iris **tien** hieraŭ.
>
> Kie estas la libro? — Ĝi estas **ĉi tie** *[tenante ĝin en la mano]*.
>
> Kien mi devus meti tiun dokumenton? — Bonvolu meti ĝin [**over there**] *[indikante]*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just say ***tie*** or ***tien***, probably the best choice when pointing at an empty location.

- *La ĝusta loko estas tie.* The correct position is over there.
- *Metu ĝin tien.* Put it over there.

However, you may also be looking for the word ***jen***, which is used to accompany the gesture of pointing, or to demand attention more generally.

- *Jen la princo!* There's the prince!
- *Kaj jen via problemo!* And there's your problem!
- *Mi preferas la jenan.* I prefer this one. [pointing]
- *La domo estas jen tie!* The house is [that one] over there!
- *Ŝi diris al li jene: ...* She spoke to him thus: ...
- *La ŝnuro rompiĝis, kaj la ĉaro ruliĝis jenen.* The rope broke, and the cart rolled down there.
- *Ni sidis ĉe la tablo, ĉiuj manĝante, kaj jen li komencis ridi.* We were sitting at the table, all of us eating, when he started to laugh.

Comment: Wow, I never knew so many uses of *jen*! I think it fits the picture perfectly.

Comment: "jenen" strikes me as very odd, probably because "jene" is not generally a location adverb.

Comment: _jene_ signifas _en la jena maniero_. Tio ne rilatas lokon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when to use **over there** versus **there** in English.

I think that it is best to just say **tie** (there) rather than over complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

There are languages with a three-distance system, for instance Japanese:

- ここに (koko ni) : here by me
- そこに (soko ni) : there by you
- あそこに (asoko ni) : somewhere else than by me or by you

Esperanto has a two-distance system, like English:

- *ĉi tie* : here, by me
- *tie* : there, somewhere else than by me

Now the English expression "over there" is an approximation to describe the third distance.

While you can approximate the three distances for things in Esperanto

- *ĉi tio* : a thing here, by me
- *tio* : a thing there, by you
- *tio tie* : a thing over there, somewhere else than by me or by you

I'm not sure, whether there exist such for locations. Perhaps *tie* as suggested by Andrew Woods with a location descriptor would do:

*Kien mi devus meti tiun dokumenton? – Bonvolu meti ĝin tien sur tiun tablon.*

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest: **malĉi tie**. :-) I’ve never seen it in use before, but I’m absolutely sure that people would understand it in an oral context:

> Kien mi devus meti la dokumenton? — Bonvolu meti ĝin **malĉi tien**.

Comment: No, people would definitely not understand "malĉi tie".  "Malĉi" has no usage history in Esperanto.

Comment: @Lee. It depends on the speakers. I have at least one very creative Esperanto-speaking friend who would *immediately* grasp it. :-) I think one of the strengths of Esperanto is that you can indeed make up situational words (w. no usage history) and be understood *in the practical context*. In his book about Esperanto, Scottish poet William Auld mentions one situation where a beginner had forgotten the word for ”birthday”. The person made up *malmortotago* on the spot – and was understood.

Comment: Jes, ankaŭ "malunua" kompreneblas kaj mi fakte tion aŭdis iam. Sed "ĉi tie" ne havas rektan malon. Kio estus malĉitie? Ĉu ĉe fino de la observebla universo? (rekta malo) Ĉu mil kilometrojn for? Dek? Je la alia flanko de la ĉambro?

Comment: La Vo-o diras '...which I would presumably be pointing to simultaneously...'. Do ne ĉe fino de la observebla universo. Mi ŝatas ĝin.